# Getting data from another table into a blade foreach - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to get data from another table into a blade foreach however my query does not show any records in the view.

connections - table:

```
Schema::create('connections', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('host_id')->unsigned();
    $table->text('comment');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('connections', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('host_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('hosts');
});
```

hosts - table:

```
Schema::create('hosts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->text('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Connections.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Connections extends Model
{
    public function hosts()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Hosts');
    }
}
```

Hosts.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Hosts extends Model
{
    public function connections()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Connections');
    }
}
```

ConnectionsController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Connections;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ConnectionsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $connections = Connections::with('hosts')->get();
        return view('connections.index', compact('connections'));
    }
}
```

views/connections/index.blade.php

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>Comment</th>
        <th>Nazwa</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($connections as $element)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $element->comment }}</td>
            <td>{{ $element->hosts->name }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

The view without "$element->hosts->name" returns "comment" value but when I add the second line with "$element->hosts->name" I get an error "Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mdbms/resources/views/connections/index.blade.php)". I wonder where there's a mistake.

Comment: What do you get if you replace `$element->hosts->name` with `var_dump($element)`?

Comment: Can you make sure in your database the foreign key for the `connection` you are working with is not null?  If the `connection` doesn't have a `host_id`, it won't load it when you use `with` which could result in the error you are seeing.

Comment: user3158900 - it isn't null because it returns the id of "host_id" when I write "$element->host_id". And the table hosts with this id contains values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `hosts` relationship function seems to be incorrect:

Change it to `return $this->belongsTo('App\Hosts', 'host_id');`

Answer (score 0):

In your case `hosts` property is array (collection) so you need to specify index or loop through it